# Why the header and footer comes after body when rendered? (Processwire)

Tags: processwire

Why the header and footer comes after body when rendered? (Planets Tutorial). The planets who are using the planet.php template are children of a page Planets which is based on basic-page.php template. The About page children pages works fine though.

site/templates/planet.php

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title><?php echo $page->title; ?></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><?php echo $page->title; ?></h1>
    <h2>
        Type: <?php echo $page->planet_type; ?>,
        Age: <?php echo $page->planet_age; ?> years
    </h2>
    <p><?php echo $page->planet_summary; ?></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's probably a bug in the software.

Comment: You're question is a little unclear. Your template does not have a header/footer. Also, ProcessWire does not alter your HTML in any way, unless you have a module installed that does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a manual intermediate install solved it.